# How to calculate Irradiance in $\rm W/m²$ from experimental data?

Tags: optics, visible-light, luminosity

i have read some questions previously asked here, but still need help.
See, i need to guarantee that a closed space(1x1x0.8m) is receiving 1,12 kW/m² of light.
I am using a 250W Siccatherm lamp, that is designed to heat spaces. In the manufacturer website it indicates that the dominant wavelenght of the light is 1100nm. I can obtain with tests, the illuminance in lux, the luminous flux in lumen, the luminous intensity in candela and the spectral distribuition of the lamp light.
How can i solve this problem properly? i never studied light in this extent, and i am not familiar with all the variables.

[image: the mounting system]

Comment: Lux is just $W/m^2$ weighted with visible light sensitivity in humans. If you have a 0.25kW lamp, I'm afraid you'll only be able to illuminate a $0.25/1.12 = 0.224 m^2$ surface at $1.12 kW/m^2$

Comment: Can you obtain/measure the _full_ spectral distribution of the lamp light for all wavelengths, most notably including near-infrared wavelengths?  If you can only obtain/measure _illuminance_ results (which are filtered to visible wavelengths), you won't be able to calculate _irradiance_ in kW/m^2 correctly at all.  Maybe a place to start is checking if your measurement equipment can operate far enough into the infrared.  (Side note - you'll also need to know the angular/spatial distribution of the lamp, as it's likely not _uniformly_ distributing its Watts over your surface area.)